# Sql query to Compare same fields of different rows in the same table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the records from `"tbl_gig"` table while comparing different rows in it.
[image]
I tried this but no luck:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_gig as t2 INNER JOIN tbl_gig as t3 
WHERE t2.gig_city=t3.gig_city 
  AND t2.artist_id=t3.artist_id 
  AND t2.partner_id < t3.partner_id 
GROUP BY t2.gig_eventDate;
```

**Expected output :**

```
gig_id   gig_artist_id  gig_partner_id
```

---

```
1        1                1
2/3      1                1/2
4        1                1
```

Please help on this.

Comment: What's the actual output? What's going wrong?

Comment: On what basis you want to combine the two rows?

Comment: You mention PHP, so why on earth would be 'combining' rows in MySQL?

Comment: Based on "partner_id", if the rows having different partner_id with same artist_id, city, country, date(don't consider time in it) should display as one row along wit other rows.

Comment: I don't understand why 2/3 are grouped? Why not 1/3? Why not 1/2/3?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   GROUP_CONCAT(gig_id SEPARATOR '/') as gig_id,
   artist_id ,
   GROUP_CONCAT(partner_id SEPARATOR '/') as partner_id
   FROM tbl_gig 
   GROUP BY artist_id
```

Comment: It is not with separating "/" I mean either of those rows should be displayed

Comment: so you could remove separate string. it must work as you asked :-) You gave us expected result - I made the query to get it :-) Do you need any help to remove separator? or what else can I help with?

Comment: Based on "partner_id", if the rows having different partner_id with same artist_id, city, country, date(don't consider time in it) should display as one row along wit other rows. Please check the screenshot not expected output once

Comment: did you check my last edit? there was typo in `GROUP BY gig_artist_id` ? if still no success could you show me the result you have using my query?